# Adding InkPicture control to my project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I need some help adding the InkPicture control to my project. I am using visual studio 2012. I tried to follow online tutorials, but I couldn't find the control. The tutorials tell me to navigate to .NET framework components tab on the customize toolbox page and check the InkPicture and hit "ok" to add the control, but when I navigate to this page I cannot find InkPicture anywhere. Any help I can get on this topic would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Hunter, welcome to SO!  You could improve your post by making your title explain more clearly and specifically the problem you are having.  It would also be helpful to provide a link to the online tutorial you are referring to.  Have you tried searching the documentation for `InkPicture`?

Comment: Right-click the toolbox, Choose Items, COM tab, tick "Microsoft InkPicture Control".